# pdf conversion problem latex

Tags: pdftex

I have a script that creates csv file and the output shown below, but when i wanted to convert this to pdf via latex then the pdf doesnot get generated. can anyone suggest me when i look at logs entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.

output of script:

```
First;DOT NET;+0176547;
Sec row;NETWORK;+12345;
+pdflatex -output-directory /tmp test.tex   -- hangs
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{longtable}{|p{8cm}|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{\B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}}} \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{\B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}}} \\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[
                separator=semicolon,
                column count=3,
                check column count,
                respect all=true,
                before reading={\catcode`\_=11},
                after reading={\catcode`\_=8},
                late after line=\\\hline
    ]{tmp.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
\end{longtable}
%\catcode`\&=4% reactivate & sign
}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please EDIT your question and add the outcome, be it a screenshot of the result, or indication about errors? // What happens, if you'd remove all "|" and "--" in your csv and separate by "," instead? Thanks

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I have given the output of csv in a table format and in csv there are no pipelines and -- and etc i did edit my question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved: the OP found the cause of the problem and is up and running again; see his/her short answer.

Comment: @MS-SPO And don't think, that Is440's answer is correct/complete. There are several mistakes in the shown code not related to the file location, but all of them should be fixed. See the second section of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to the original question:

There are several issues with your code, e.g., wrong bracing, wrong `separator`, table has 5 columns (one before the first `|` and one after the last `|` per row), etc.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
| A        | B              |c        |
| -------- | -------------- |-------- |
| First    | DOT NET        |+0176547 |
| Sec row  | NETWORK        |+12345   |
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{8cm}|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}} \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}} \\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[
                separator=pipe,
                column count = 5,
                check column count,
                range = 2-4,
                head to column names,
                late after line=\\\hline
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{ \A & \B & \c }
\end{longtable}
%\catcode`\&=4% reactivate & sign
\end{document}
```

### Answer to the question with changed example:

There are still mistakes in your code, e.g.,

```
    \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{\B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}}} \\\hline
```

Here you have two `{` in the last cell but three `}`. Which results in error message:

> Missing { inserted.

You can find this mistake twice in your code.

Similar line

```
}}
```

closes two groups, that never have been opened and also results in two error messages:

> Too many }'s

Following would work without error (and without need to use `csvsimple-l3`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.csv}
First;DOT NET;+0176547;
Sec row;NETWORK;+12345;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}} \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \textbf{\textsf{A}} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{\textsf{C}} \\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \csvreader[
                head=false,
                separator=semicolon,
                column count = 3,
                late after line=\\\hline
    ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry there seems to misunderstanding i have changed the output of script, I am not passing table in to tex file..

Comment: strange thing is when i run the same on overleaf i get pdf generated

Comment: As far as I know Overleaf tends to be less strict, perhaps to ease work for a broader group of users. However, in return you build-in errors, which go undetected, unless ... you switch to a local installation, which is not (based on) Overleaf.

Comment: @ls440 Overleaf shows the errors even if it is able to also show a PDF. AFAIK there are red marks in the right frame of the browser window. And it is also possible to visit (or download) the log-file. So don't need to use a local installation to find the errors. One may not necessarily be thrown out on a limb. But the error messages are available.

Answer (score -1):

Its my bad, I just have to copy .tex file under the correct path. it works now Thanks everyone

Comment: There are definitely mistakes in your code (e.g. more `}` than `{`), which result in errors. Even, if Overleaf is able to show you a PDFs, this doesn't mean, you should ignore errors. You always should fix all errors.